# RegisterApplicationRestart with different path

Tags: winapi

I have two applications. Both of them use the same resources. Lets call these resources "profile resources". Application B cannot be started up until Application A shutsdown. So I have app A running and was trying to shut it down, then launch up with app B path. I explored `RegisterApplicationRestart` but I could not accomplish it. Is this possible to be done? I'm getting stuck at the point where Application A is shutdown, then I cant run any code to launch back App B.

Comment: `RegisterApplicationRestart` will not perform a restart if the application terminates normally. It is not designed to do so. You have got the wrong function. My guess though is that App A and App B are firefox.exe, so you likely need a separate executable file.

Comment: Also, if the app terminates abnormally, or hangs, triggering a restart, the user is prompted whether to actually perform the restart or not.  The registered app is restarted automatically only if the OS is rebooted with the EWX_RESTARTAPPS flag, such as by an installer that needs to replace files on running apps.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan thanks very much yep what my user as done is they have firefox.exe and firefox_beta.exe and firefox_alpha.exe and then firefox_nightly.exe, they are running firefox.exe have clicked a button to restart firefox into firefox_***.exe. Currently I have a shortcut file that has target set to firefox.exe, so when they change the build to beta I change the target of the shortcut and then I need to relaunch that shortcut after shutdown.

Comment: You'll need control of one of the executables.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan! Do you mean for Remy's technqiue below? I'm in control of Exe A :)

Comment: Easiest is another executable. But you could use exe A in a new process that in turn starts exe B.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan for that recommendation! I'm not able to do other exe's as this is from addon :( I can make other shortcuts though (as those are made on runtime, exe requires compiling :( ).

Comment: You'll want to start a new process with exe A passing arguments to specify behaviour.

Comment: Got it thanks @Dave I'll report back how it goes :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is it possible to use argv modification for this?

Comment: If you control the executable, you can do what you like with its arguments

Comment: Thank @DavidHeffernan i was worried though that if argv is changed then I have to set it to have <= initial string length no? Or does argv allocate MAX_PATH?

Comment: Modifying `argv` while the process is still running is useless.  You need to start a **new copy** of the .exe file so you can pass it different command-line parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` can launch `B` using [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) before exiting, passing its own process handle to `B`. Before `B` accesses the resource, it can wait on `A`'s handle using [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) or related function. When the handle is signaled, `A` has fully terminated, so `B` can close the handle using [`CloseHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx) and move on as needed.

To pass `A`'s process handle to `B`, `A` can either:

1. open its own process handle using [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) with [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180.aspx) as the process ID, mark the handle as inheritable using [`SetHandleInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724935.aspx), and then pass the handle value to `B` as a command-line parameter, setting the `bInheritHandles` parameter of `CreateProcess()` to TRUE.
2. Run `B` first and have it create an IPC listener (named pipe, mailslot, socket, etc), then `A` can duplicate its own process handle for `B`'s use via [`DuplicateHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx) with [`GetCurrentProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179.aspx) as the source handle and `B`'s process handle (from `CreateProcess()`) as the target process, then send the duplicate handle value to `B` via IPC.

A simpler technique is to have `A` pass its own process ID, rather than its process handle, to `B` as a command-line parameter, then `B` can use [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to open `A`'s process handle.  Although this will usually work, it does have a small race condition - before `B` has a chance to open the process handle, `A` might terminate and the OS could reuse its process ID for a new unrelated process, thus `B` would get a handle to, and wait on, the wrong process.

Comment: Thanks @Remy! I'll test this out and report back! edit: Ah i don't have control of application B. Only application A is mine, will this still work?

Comment: Yes, with a slight modification.  `A` can run another copy of itself, which can wait for the original to exit as described above, before then running `B`.  `A` would have to look at its command-line parameters to know whether it is the original or the copy, and can then act accordingly.